# Is this a right Numpy reshape?

Tags: python, numpy

I've just started with Python and Numpy.

I have found this piece of code:

```
def preprocessing(FLAIR_array, T1_array):

    brain_mask = np.ndarray(np.shape(FLAIR_array), dtype=np.float32)
    brain_mask[FLAIR_array >=thresh] = 1
    brain_mask[FLAIR_array < thresh] = 0
    for iii in range(np.shape(FLAIR_array)[0]):
        brain_mask[iii,:,:] = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes(brain_mask[iii,:,:])  #fill the holes inside brain

    FLAIR_array -=np.mean(FLAIR_array[brain_mask == 1])      #Gaussion Normalization
    FLAIR_array /=np.std(FLAIR_array[brain_mask == 1])

    rows_o = np.shape(FLAIR_array)[1]
    cols_o = np.shape(FLAIR_array)[2]
    FLAIR_array = FLAIR_array[:, int((rows_o-rows_standard)/2):int((rows_o-rows_standard)/2)+rows_standard, int((cols_o-cols_standard)/2):int((cols_o-cols_standard)/2)+cols_standard]
```

What are they doing in the last line? In this one:

```
FLAIR_array[:, int((rows_o-rows_standard)/2):int((rows_o-rows_standard)/2)+rows_standard, int((cols_o-cols_standard)/2):int((cols_o-cols_standard)/2)+cols_standard]
```

`FLAIR_array` has this shape: [48,240,240].

48 is the number of images.
240, 240 is its height and witdh.

Or maybe, they are slicing it.

Comment: Looks like it's slicing a centered window from each image, e.g. `FLAIR_array[:, 100:140, 90:150]` to produce a (48, 40, 60) array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're only performing [Numpy slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) (and not reshaping) on `FLAIR_array` whose resultant dimensions will be:

- All elements in the 0th dimension are retained from the original array (as indicated by `:`)
- Elements `int((rows_o-rows_standard)/2)` to `int((rows_o-rows_standard)/2)+rows_standard - 1` are used from 1st dimension from the original array
- Elements `int((cols_o-cols_standard)/2)` to `int((cols_o-cols_standard)/2)+cols_standard - 1` are used from 2nd dimension from the original array

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, it will have the same shape but with less elements, isn't it?

Comment: Yes totally. Slicing reduces number of elements while reshaping preserves the number of elements but arranged in a different order across different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, as rows standard is not defined inside the function.
But if you rewrite it as (dropping some of the int(..) to increase readability)

```
rows_center = int(rows_o/2)
cols_center = int(cols_o/2)
delta_rows = int(rows_standard)
delta_cols = int(cols_standard)
FLAIR_array = FLAIR_array[:, rows_center - rows_delta/2:rows_center + rows_delta/2, cols_center - cols_delta/2:cols_center + cols_delta/2]
```

It seems that they are extracting for each image a small crop centered at rows_center and cols_center with the number of rows and columns equal to delta_rows, delta_cols